# Formation of Trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

> Finding equation  in terms of variable $x$ whose roots are $\displaystyle \tan\left(\frac{(4n+1)\pi}{16}\right)$ for $n=0,1,2,3$

Try: $$\tan\bigg(n\theta\bigg)=\frac{\binom{n}{1}\tan\theta-\binom{n}{3}\tan^3\theta+\binom{n}{5}\tan^5\theta\cdots\cdots}{1-\binom{n}{2}\tan^2\theta+\binom{n}{4}\tan^4\theta\cdots}$$

Substitute $\displaystyle\bigg(\frac{(4n+1)\pi}{16}\bigg)=\theta$ and put $n=16$

We have $$\binom{16}{1}\tan \theta-\binom{16}{3}\tan^3\theta+\binom{16}{5}\tan^5\theta\cdots\cdots\cdots=0$$

Could some help me to solve it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Risky reusage of $n$

Put $n=4$ in $\tan n\theta$

where $4\theta=\dfrac{(4m+1)\pi}4, m=0,1,2,3$

Comment: I did not understand please simplify more, thnks

Comment: @Durgesh, $\tan4\theta=?$

Comment: $\tan(4\theta)=\pm 1$

Comment: @Durgesh, Why $\pm1?$ $$\tan(m\pi+x)=+\tan x$$ right?